# How to repeat escape character n times in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Say I want to repeat `&nbsp;` 3 times in `span` tag and the final result will be `<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>`
If it is a normal character, I can simply use the code snippet below to archive this requirement

```
<span>{'x'.repeat(3)}</span>
```

But now it is an escape character, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are in Javascript, not in HTML, therefore you can simply:

```
<span>{'\xa0'.repeat(3)}</span>
```

However also note that this would be better achieved using `:before` or `:after` CSS attributes.